# How to cluster Mixtile Blade 3 nodes, which are partially equipped with U.2 drives

Tags: san, single-board, ceph

I'm planning to build a cluster of single-board computers I could then use as file (using Ceph) and database (Postgres XL) server. As the performance of the [Mixtile Blade 3](https://www.mixtile.com/blade-3/) quite impresses me, I think I will couple a handful of them into a cluster.

However, I've got the following issue:

Some of these nodes (4 of them at the beginning) will be equipped with one SSD each, whereas the rest will be used as computing nodes. The Mixtile Blade has a 4-lane PCIe 3 port, which can be used either for attaching an SSD, or for daisy-chaining nodes into a high-speed network. Once the PCIe port has an SSD on it, it's no longer available for daisy-chaining.

Shall I then connect the two 2.5 GBit ethernet ports of the storage nodes (with the PCIe SSDs) to a switch, bond them (`eth0` + `eth1` → `bond0`) to get 5 GBit / sec and then also network the remaining nodes in the same manner? Will this allow to access the SSDs from all cluster nodes without compromising speed, latency, or safety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a PCIe switch to connect all Blade 3 boards (2-lane each board) and leave the remaining 2-lane for the SSD. Please see the topology graph:
[image: 1].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).